# Using the CASE function in MYSQL with Zend_DB_Expr

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I'm stuck with the following problem. In my product table i've two columns

Date_start and Date_end (both of them are a DATE datatype in my table).

I want to check if the current date is between the Date_start and Date_end then the status must be 'not available', else it must have the status 'available'.

How can I fix that in Zend_Db_Expr?

I've now the following query.

```
$getProducts = $this->oSelect
                            ->from(array('p'=>'producten'))
                            ->columns(array('link' => "CONCAT('/t/', p.titel_key)"))
                            ->joinLeft(array('c'=>'categorie'),'p.categorie_id = c.id',array('cat_titel'=>'c.titel'))
                            ->joinLeft(array('sc'=>'subcategorie'),'p.subcategorie_id = sc.id', array('subcat_titel'=>'sc.titel'))
                            ->where('p.online = 1');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your columns:

```
->columns(array('link' => "CONCAT('/t/', p.titel_key)",
  'status' => new Zend_Db_Expr("...")))
```

The 'CASE' should look something like this (i split it out for readability);

```
CASE WHEN p.Date_end < NOW() AND p.Date_start > NOW() 
THEN 'not available' ELSE 'available' END
```

Zend_Db_Expr will take anything you give it and use it literally.  Just remember that any DB specific commands might break if for some reason you switch systems.

Comment: Thank you Darryl i'll try this out and figure it bymself.

Comment: "Just remember that any DB specific commands might break if for some reason you switch systems." Can you tell me more about this please?? I just want to do this: `<?php echo new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'); ?>" />` in a view but I just got a literal "NOW()" and not a date. I had to uninstall my PHP+MySQL and reinstall for other reasons. Why my Zend_Db_Expr() doesn't works? THANKS!